# how to retrieve values of numeric column names of table from vue axios response

Tags: vue.js

So my table structure is as below

id | name | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | created_at | updated_at

I want to get the value of columns 1,2,3, and 4 from the response object of vue axios call.

```
axios.get('/someAPIpage/').then(response => {
    this.name = response.data[0].name;
    this.a1 = response.data[0].1;
    this.a2 = response.data[0].2;
    this.a3 = response.data[0].3;
    this.a4 = response.data[0].4;
  });
```

But i am not successful at that may be because my column's names are numeric. So how can i get these numeric column values? Any help appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with VueJS, please change the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```js
axios.get('/someAPIpage/').then(response => {
  this.name = response.data[0].name;
  this.a1 = response.data[0]['1'];
  this.a2 = response.data[0]['2'];
  this.a3 = response.data[0]['3'];
  this.a4 = response.data[0]['4'];
});
```